# How to query Solr apache php array one value

Tags: php, search, solr

I have data

```
id = [1,2,3]
id = [2]
id = [2,3]
id = [1,3]
id = [2]
```

Expected results:

```
id = [2]
id = [2]
```

Current results:

```
id = [1,2,3]
id = [2]
id = [2,3]
id = [2]
```

My current query:

```
$query->createFilterQuery('id')->setQuery('id:2');
```

I just want to get arrays that have one value, and it will be equal to the value I passed in like 1 or 2 or 3. As in the above example, I pass the value = 3, the result will return null.

Thank everyone!

Comment: Would `id:2 AND NOT id:[* TO 2} AND NOT id:{2 TO *]` work? (i.e. "anything that has the id 2, and not an id that is lower than 2 or an id that is larger than 2) - The difference between `{` and `[` is that one is exclusive and one is inclusive the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like `id:2 AND NOT id:[* TO 2} AND NOT id:{2 TO *]`. It'll effectively search for any documents that have `2` in the `id` field, and then remove any documents that have any value less than or more than the desired `id` value.

The difference between `{` and `[` is that one is exclusive and the other is inclusive of the value itself.